# Как выделить активную ссылку в меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сейчас добавляется `active`, если находишься в категории `site.ru/closed/`,

а если находиься на таких страницах `site.ru/closed/page/2/` `site.ru/closed/news.html` то уже класс не добавляется.

Как к таким страницам добавить `active`?

```
<ul class="hoe-sub-menu">                            
    <li>
        <a href="/closed/">
            <span class="menu-text">Closed</span>
        </a>
    </li>                             
    <li>
        <a href="/vip/">
            <span class="menu-text">Vip</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...                            
</ul>
```

и

```
$('.hoe-sub-menu li a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Я вангую, что класс `active` добавляет CMS, но уж никак не JS.

Comment: Нет не CMS, а тот код